# How can I shrink an SD card to a smaller sized SD card?

Tags: sd-card

I recently have been doing work with [RetroPie](https://retropie.org.uk/) and started building things out on a large (128GB) SD card. After getting everything set up I realized I was only using ~62GB of this space.

How can I shrink this SD so that'll fit on a smaller sized SD card using the CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** For this method we're going to extract the SD into a IMG file and then resize that, and turn around and rewrite the reduced size IMG file back to a smaller SD card. You'll need suitable space on your Mac to do this!

#### Solution

In looking I found several [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) tools that looked to be able to do the job.

- [PiShrink](https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink)
- [ShrinkPi](https://florianmuller.com/quickly-resize-and-shrink-raspberry-pi-sd-card-image-on-macos)

Of these I opted to use the 2nd one, whose executable is `pishrink`.

#### Example

First I took a IMG file of my 128GB SD card. For this you can use either [BalenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) or [ApplePi-Baker](https://www.tweaking4all.com/software/macosx-software/applepi-baker-v2/). Both of these will produce a suitable IMG file.

For the [IMG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMG_(file_format)) file, open the Terminal application and cd into the directory where you saved it. Then type:

ls -lh filename-of-img-file.img

```
$ ls -lh retropie1-jb.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 120G Jan 21 01:07 retropie1-jb.img
```

After installing ShrinkPi:

```
$ curl -LO https://github.com/lisanet/PiShrink-macOS/archive/master.zip
$ unzip master
$ cd PiShrink-macOS-master
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

We can then use it to shrink the ~120GB IMG file:

```
$ pishrink retropie1-jb.img retropie1-jb__sm.img
Copying retropie1-jb.img to retropie1-jb__sm.img...
e2fsck 1.44.0 (7-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
retropie: 220054/7616736 files (0.9% non-contiguous), 16130407/31245056 blocks
resize2fs 1.44.0 (7-Mar-2018)
resize2fs 1.44.0 (7-Mar-2018)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/disk4s2 to 16143286 (4k) blocks.
Begin pass 2 (max = 1106914)
Relocating blocks             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Begin pass 3 (max = 954)
Scanning inode table          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Begin pass 4 (max = 22654)
Updating inode references     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
The filesystem on /dev/disk4s2 is now 16143286 (4k) blocks long.

"disk4" ejected.
fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory
Enter 'help' for information
fdisk: 1>          Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2: 83  976   0   1 - 1023  63  32 [    124928 -  249960448] Linux files*
Partition id ('0' to disable)  [0 - FF]: [83] (? for help) Do you wish to edit in CHS mode? [n] Partition offset [0 - 250085376]: [124928] Partition size [1 - 249960448]: [249960448] fdisk:*1> Writing MBR at offset 0.
fdisk: 1> Shrunk retropie1-jb__sm.img from 119G to 62G
```

We can then use either BalenaEtcher or ApplePi-Baker to take the smaller IMG file and rewrite it to a smaller SD card.